# C++ variadic template empty packet case

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I'm very new to meta-programming and I was trying to play around with variadic templates. I've searched a lot on StackOverflow and came across multiple solutions for my problem but I couldn't seem to make them work. The code I have is the following:

```
template <typename TA, typename... TB>
class A
{
public:
    inline long long f()
    {
        // 6 is just a placeholder, the value 
        // comes from a dummy object which is a class member
        return g<TB...>(6); 
    }

[...]

private:
    template <typename Head, typename Head2, typename ...Tail>
    inline long long g(long long x)
    {
        return (&Head::instance())->external_function(g<Head2, Tail...>(x));
    }

    template<typename Head>
    inline long long g(long long x) {
        return (&Head::instance())->external_function(x);
    }

    inline long long g(long long x) {
        return x;
    }

[...]
```

Where TB can be 0 or more elements.
So what I was trying to achieve is to call a method `external_function` in cascade which I know every element inside TB has defined.
It works if TB has one element, but if TB is empty, what I get is that I have no function matching g<>.

Then I tried to redefine the three overloaded functions as follows

```
template <typename Head, typename ...Tail>
inline long long g(long long x)
{
    return (&Head::instance())->external_function(g<Tail...>(x));
}

template<typename Head>
inline long long g(long long x) {
    return (&Head::instance())->external_function(x);
}

template<typename = void>
inline long long g(long long x) {
    return x;
}
```

But still no luck.

So what I tried again was to use two specialised functions, one that accepts one or more arguments and the other that is called only when there are zero arguments

```
template <typename Head, typename ...Tail>
inline long long g(long long x)
{
    return (&Head::instance())-> external_function(g<Tail...>(x));
}


template<typename... Tail>
inline long long g(long long x) {
    return x;
}
```

But again, what I get is that this last solution only works if TB is empty. If it contains at least one element I get an error about an ambiguous call.

I'm getting lost with variadic functions and their base cases also because their usage has changed a lot during the years with C++11, C++17 and C++20. I've seen that fold expressions can solve the problem and make the code more readable, but I had no luck trying to use them for cascade calls.

Really hope someone can help me shed light on this.

Edit: For project reasons, I'm stuck with C++14 and below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With C++14, you can achieve what you need by using partial **class** specialization:

```
template <typename TA, typename... TB>
class A
{
public:
    inline long long f()
    {
        // 6 is just a placeholder, the value 
        // comes from a dummy object which is a class member
        return g_impl<TB...>::call(6LL); 
    }

private:

    // base specialization, fallback for 0 elements
    template<typename... Ts>
    struct g_impl
    {
        static inline long long call(long long x)
        {
            std::cout << "empty typelist case\n";
            return x;
        }
    };

    // 1 or more elements
    template< typename Head, typename... Tail>
    struct g_impl<Head, Tail...>
    {
        static inline long long call(long long x)
        {
            std::cout << (sizeof...(Tail) + 1) << " types case\n";
            return (&Head::instance())->external_function(g_impl<Tail...>::call(x));
        }
    };
};
```

---

Let's test with the following identical classes:

```
struct Test1
{
    long long external_function(long long x){std::cout << "Test1::external_function\n"; return 42;}
    static Test1& instance()
    {
        static Test1 self;
        return self;
    }
};

struct Test2
{
    long long external_function(long long x){std::cout << "Test2::external_function\n"; return 42;}
    static Test2& instance()
    {
        static Test2 self;
        return self;
    }
};

struct Test3
{
    long long external_function(long long x){std::cout << "Test3::external_function\n"; return 42;}
    static Test3& instance()
    {
        static Test3 self;
        return self;
    }
}
```

And call it from `main` like so:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "---\n";
    std::cout << "Testing A<Test1>\n";
    A<Test1> a;
    a.f();

    std::cout << "---\n";
    std::cout << "Testing A<Test1, Test2>\n";
    A<Test1, Test2> b{};
    b.f();

    std::cout << "---\n";
    std::cout << "Testing A<Test1, Test2, Test3>\n";
    A<Test1, Test2, Test3> c;
    c.f();
    std::cout << "---\n";
}
```

Output:

```
---
Testing A<Test1>
empty typelist case
---
Testing A<Test1, Test2>
1 types case
empty typelist case
Test2::external_function
---
Testing A<Test1, Test2, Test3>
2 types case
1 types case
empty typelist case
Test3::external_function
Test2::external_function
---
```

### [Live Demo (clang, gcc, and msvc)](https://godbolt.org/z/WT8zTzEMq)

---

In C++20 we can squeeze this all into a single recursive template function:

```
template<typename... Ts>
inline long long g(long long x)
{
    // empty typelist
    if constexpr(sizeof...(Ts) == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Empty typelist case\n";
        return x;
    }
    else
    {
        // 1 or more in typelist
        std::cout << sizeof...(Ts) << " in typelist\n";
        auto callable = [=]<class Head, class... Tail>
        {
            return Head::instance().external_function(g<Tail...>(x));
        };
        return callable.template operator()<Ts...>();
    }
}
```

### [C++20 Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rvhf4o3re)

---

EDIT: Per OP's request, they'd *also* like to reverse the parameter pack before the calls, which requires some boilerplate to create the notion of a typelist (empty class) and perform operations on it to reverse it, and then later extract the types:

```
template<class... Ts>
struct typelist{};

template<class... Ts, class... Us>
auto concat(typelist<Ts...>, typelist<Us...>) -> typelist<Ts..., Us...>;

auto reverse(typelist<>) -> typelist<>;

template<class Head, class... Tail>
auto reverse(typelist<Head, Tail...>)
    -> decltype(
        concat(
               reverse(std::declval<typelist<Tail...>>()),
               std::declval<typelist<Head>>()
               ) // concat
      ); // decltype

template<class... Ts>
using reversed_typelist = decltype(reverse(std::declval<typelist<Ts...>>()));
```

Then we add another level of indirection on calling `f()`:

```
public:
    inline long long f()
    {
        // 6 is just a placeholder, the value 
        // comes from a dummy object which is a class member
        return f_impl(reversed_typelist<TB...>{}, 6LL); 
    }

private:

    template<class... Ts>
    inline long long f_impl(typelist<Ts...>, long long x)
    {
        return g_impl<Ts...>::call(x);
    }
```

Now that we've reversed the parameter pack, the output demonstrates the calls in reverse order as before:

```
---
Testing A<Test1>
empty typelist case
---
Testing A<Test1, Test2>
1 types case
empty typelist case
Test2::external_function
---
Testing A<Test1, Test2, Test3>
2 types case
1 types case
empty typelist case
Test2::external_function
Test3::external_function
---
```

### [C++14 demo with reversed parameter pack](https://godbolt.org/z/j7jY659xT)

Comment: That worked like a charm :) Before I flag your question as the solution, is there a way to reverse the typelist before calling the function `call`? So define another struct, let's say `g2_impl`, that receives the pack in reverse order? I tried to implement it with template `<typename ...Head, typename Tail>` and `struct g2_impl<Head..., Tail>` but no luck since it tells me "parameter pack argument 'Head ...' must be at the end of the template argument list".

Comment: Sure it's possible to reverse a typelist. To clarify, though, you only want to reverse the parameter pack TB before the first call?

Comment: yes exactly! A function `inline long long f2()` that do something like `return g_impl<REVERSE(TB...)>::call(6LL);`. I'm also not sure if the reverse should take place before the call or let the functions handle it backwards maybe matching something like `<first n-1 parameters, last parameter>`

Comment: @Codexy I've added the parameter pack reversal logic. Hope that helps.

Comment: I was expecting the parameter pack reversal logic to be more simple, guess I have a lot more to learn about meta programming! Truly magical for me, but very helpful